# Finding variable names in vue components

Tags: vue.js

I have a list of variable names in my program
I want to look in all my components in vue and see which component each variable is used in.

For example :

`let x = ['test_one', 'test_two'];`

find in all components for uses someone

```js
// Example.vue
<template>
     {{ x }}
</template>

<script setup>
    const test_one = ref('hello');
    const x = ref('abcd');
</script>
```

find `test_one` exists in `Example.vue`
find `test_two` exists in `Example.vue`

Do you know of a way I can look for variables in my components?

Comment: it's not related to Vue. just use global text search in your IDE or `grep` command

Answer (score 1):

If I understood correctly, you can use `defineExpose` macro in child component, then use a ref on that component in parent one :

Example.vue

```html
<template>
     {{ x }}
</template>

<script setup>
   import {ref} from 'vue'
    
    const test_one = ref('hello');
    const x = ref('abcd');

   defineExpose({test_one,x})

</script>
```

in parent component :

```html
<script setup>
import { ref } from 'vue'
import Example from './Example.vue'
const example =ref()

console.log("Example value: ",example.value)
</script>

<template>
  
  <Example ref="example"/>
</template>
```